# How are remote afp filesystems automatically mounted

Tags: networking, 20.04, gvfs

Ubuntu 20.04  GNOME Version 3.36.8
I have a remote volume that mounts as:
/run/user/1000/gvfs/'afp-volume:host=Stora.local,user=mrhickman,volume=mrhickman'

At least I think this is the mount point because I cannot find any information on how this volume gets mounted.

If I use nautilus to unmount the volume, the entry disappears from the gvfs folder above.  The Stora icon is still visible in nautilus, clicking on it and, subsequently, the mrhickman folder that appears will cause the afp-volume entry above to reappear.

The problem I am trying to solve is that this volume is not available post suspend for my backup routine.  I currently must browse the mrhickman volume in nautilus before backup tries to access it.  I cannot find any command-line tools that I can use to re-attach to this volume automatically with a post-suspend script.

I tried gio mount -u when the volume is mounted and browsable in nautilus but it reports that the volume is not mounted.  If I follow with gio mount -l, it reports:

```
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
  Volume(0): 983 GB Volume
    Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
  Volume(1): EFI0
    Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Drive(1): WDC  WDS100T2B0A-00SM50
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
Volume(0): mark.r.hickman@gmail.com
  Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorGoa)
Mount(0): mrhickman for mrhickman on Stora -> afp://mrhickman@Stora.local/mrhickman/
  Type: GDaemonMount
```

`mount | grep mrhickman` returns nothing

while the info pages for gvfs are installed, I can't access the commands either as normal or superuser.

Can anyone tell me how this volume gets mounted at power-up and why it does not respond after resuming from suspend?